# notify application via callback notification

Tags: apigee

I saw Apigee provides push notification capabilities via Apple APN and Google GCM but would it be possible to notify 3rd party application via custom HTTP interface which it may expose? For example, when app subscribes for events it provides a callback URI which should be triggered in case of event.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Apigee App Services only offers push notifications for Apple and Android.  However, you could do what you want by using API Services and creating an API Proxy that does a callout to the custom notification interface.  You could create multiple API proxies, one for each custom Http interface you want to implement.